# Binary-safe backup of MySQL database using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I used http://davidwalsh.name/backup-mysql-database-php to backup my mysql database. But it destroys binary data(blobs) in the database. That means, importing the generated files creates blobs that are not readable.

What should be changed?

For your convenience, here's the code:

```
backup_tables('localhost','username','password','blog');


/* backup the db OR just a table */
function backup_tables($host,$user,$pass,$name,$tables = '*')
{

  $link = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
  mysql_select_db($name,$link);

  //get all of the tables
  if($tables == '*')
  {
    $tables = array();
    $result = mysql_query('SHOW TABLES');
    while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
    {
      $tables[] = $row[0];
    }
  }
  else
  {
    $tables = is_array($tables) ? $tables : explode(',',$tables);
  }

  //cycle through
  foreach($tables as $table)
  {
    $result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM '.$table);
    $num_fields = mysql_num_fields($result);

    $return.= 'DROP TABLE '.$table.';';
    $row2 = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query('SHOW CREATE TABLE '.$table));
    $return.= "\n\n".$row2[1].";\n\n";

    for ($i = 0; $i < $num_fields; $i++) 
    {
      while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
      {
        $return.= 'INSERT INTO '.$table.' VALUES(';
        for($j=0; $j<$num_fields; $j++) 
        {
          $row[$j] = addslashes($row[$j]);
          $row[$j] = ereg_replace("\n","\\n",$row[$j]);
          if (isset($row[$j])) { $return.= '"'.$row[$j].'"' ; } else { $return.= '""'; }
          if ($j<($num_fields-1)) { $return.= ','; }
        }
        $return.= ");\n";
      }
    }
    $return.="\n\n\n";
  }

  //save file
  $handle = fopen('db-backup-'.time().'-'.(md5(implode(',',$tables))).'.sql','w+');
  fwrite($handle,$return);
  fclose($handle);
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using `mysqldump`?

Comment: Note that ereg_replace deprecated as of PHP 5.3.0.

Comment: @Jack Yes. mysqldump 'mydb' > 'databases/db-backup-1354025541.sql' creates an empty db-backup-1354025541.sql.

Comment: Instead of giving @Jack more votes up, read my reply.

Comment: Are you calling mysqldump from the shell or from PHP? If it's from PHP, there might be some file permission or database access issue that needs to be corrected.

Comment: To debug you should add 2>&1 behind the statement to check for any errors.

Comment: @JonathanAmend When using PHPShell I get *mysqldump: Got error: 1045: Access denied for user 'myusername'@'localhost' (using password: NO) when trying to connect*

Comment: You need to provide user name and password when invoking `mysqldump`, with `-u` and `-p` options. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqldump.html

Comment: Now this is working: *mysqldump --port 3306 -u uname --password=pw -h localhost --databases mydb --add-drop-table > databases/db-backup-1354025541.sql*

Answer (score 0):

I'll just be going by the comments on this post.

When you run other processes from within PHP you should check for return codes, e.g.:

```
// execute process and capture output and return code in $out and $res
exec('/path/to/command', $out, $res);
if ($res) {
    // the process didn't return with code 0
}
```

In your case, `$out` would be empty because `stderr` is used to print error messages; to show those in the captured output you can redirect `stderr` like so:

```
exec('/path/to/command 2>&1', $out, $res);
```

A more complex setup whereby the various input / output streams of another process can be handled separately involves using `proc_open()`, but that's pretty advanced stuff and probably not necessary in your case.